# Expand Tree to a specific level

Tags: jquery, fancytree

How can I use `node.setExpanded(true);` to expand the tree only to a certain level?

What I mean is that I've got 6 depth-levels and only want 5 to be expanded -- the last one should be excluded.

Comment: A recursive function passing the remaining level count would do, but you really need to show the code you have attempted :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    $("#treeView").fancytree("getRootNode").visit(function(node){
        if(node.getLevel() < 3) {
            node.setExpanded(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It would be best to explain how this code helps the OP, especially as there is an existing accepted answer on this two year old question.

Comment: it was vital back then but thanks for the approach :-) maybe it helps somebody else too :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is just a guide, as you have provided no sample data or code, but you can use a recursive function to iterate the tree, stopping when a specific depth is reached. Something like:

```
function expandNode(node, depth) {
    // Expand this node
    node.setExpanded(true);
    // Reduce the depth count
    depth--;
    // If we need to go deeper
    if (depth > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            // Go recursive on child nodes
            expandNode(node.children[i], depth);
        }
    }
}
```

and call it with the root node and overall depth:

```
expandNode(rootNode, 5);
```

*There may well be better methods to iterate a fancytree, but I have not used fancytree before*

Comment: thanks a lot, sorry for not providing any code. i've used

$("#tree").fancytree("getRootNode").visit(function(node){
        node.setExpanded(true);
     });
for expanding every node beginning from the rootnode!

Comment: @Andreas Zeiner: Code and example html would have meant a working demo, but you get the idea from this example I hope :)

Comment: works perfekt! you're a star and may the last ninja be with you :-) yes a played them all on the c64 - been there since 1985!

Comment: you could also use `node.visit(...)`and `if( node.getLevel() < 6)...`

Comment: @mar10: That's the `fancytree` specific stuff I don't know about. Why don't you post an answer?